# checking if file exists and vba thinks its there, type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

With the below code, ever since I have tried to condense it to a complex if, VBA thinks the files is there when it is not. Is it because of my declaration? Previous I had it ordered in this fashion (before the complicated if) and it worked fine. When I rearrange my declarations of the filelocations then it still thinks the file is there. Then I tried changing the ElseIf part to say ' <> "" ' and separated it into two separate IF's and yet the same result.

EDITED with correct end result

```
      If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(filelocation1) Then
    filelocation1 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xls"
    filelocation2 = "\\afsaztempe1na1\site\AFS-AZ-Tempe\Shared\CERTIFICATION\ProdDumpTest" & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & Application.UserName & ".xls"
    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Production")

    If wsI.Range("A2").value = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    With wbO
        Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filelocation1, FileFormat:=56
        wsI.Range("A1:C100").Copy
        wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End With

    With wsI
        wsI.Range("A2:C200").ClearContents
    End With

    FileCopy Source:=filelocation1, Destination:=filelocation2
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

 filelocation1 = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop" & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xls"
filelocation2 = "\\afsaztempe1na1\site\AFS-AZ-Tempe\Shared\CERTIFICATION\ProdDumpTest" & "\" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy") & Application.UserName & ".xls"

If filelocation1 <> "" Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Production")

With wbO
    Set wbO = Workbooks.Open(filelocation1)
    If wsI.Range("A2").value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")
    wsI.Range("a2:c100").Copy
    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End With

With wb1
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(filelocation2)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsI.Range("a2:c100").Copy
    ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End With

With wsI
    wsI.Range("A2:C200").ClearContents
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End If

Comment: `filelocation1` is never going to be equal to `""` as you've declared the string variable and assigned a string to it. Are you sure you're not looking for the `DIR()` function?

Comment: Well even if I move the declaration around i still get a type mismatch error. See edited code.

Comment: Also I guess I will look up the DIR function as it sounds like that might eb the issue

Comment: `filelocation1` is just a string... i don't think `Set wbO = filelocation1` will ever work... (I assume `wbO` is an object)

Comment: @DirkReichel. Works perfectly Thanks. Now Ive run into the issue where my "offset" logic isnt applying.

Comment: you sure it is not the `PasteSpecial`? After pasting the save + close normally kills your copy... try to copy it always directly before pasting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to check the existence of a file, you can do it this way:

```
If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(filelocation1) Then
```

Also, to open a Workbook from a given name, you should do it this way:

```
Set wbO = Workbooks.Add(filelocation1)
```

Comment: This is and Changing Worksbooks.add to Workbooks.Open in the second half did the trick. Thanks